# Are all platforms vulnerable to RAT's?

Tags: security, remote-access, spyware

I just resently found out about RAT and Keyloggers (Remote Administration Tool) that is used by "hackers" to take controll over a cumputeres.

[Here is some information on the topic.](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/03/rat-breeders-meet-the-men-who-spy-on-women-through-their-webcams/)

Is linux affected the same way Windows is?

Comment: Hi Nik - over on Security Stack Exchange we have answers from experienced security professionals. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyloggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the distribution. There's certainly a lot less viruses written for Linux, but some Linux distributions are so secure that they won't allow any unsigned applications to run at all and therefore virtually impervious to infection. Of course, a lot of the time it's the end users fault for executing something they shouldn't be, so infection rate is ultimately down to the person using the machine.

Remote admin tools are just a windows thing as far as I know. Most Linux users remotely admin boxes using putty to gain a secure SSH connection and run commands directly rather then through a remote tool.